# Loading CSV file with 2.5 million records

Tags: php, arrays, csv, import

I have a large CSV file with every postcode in the UK, it comes to 2,558,797 records and I need to import it, manipulate the data by sorting it into a multi-dimensional array before saving the data in the multi-dimensional array in the database.

The problem is if I try and access the whole file I get an allowed memory exceeded exception. I can access about 128,000 records in any one go. Is there a way I can split the task down so that I can process the whole file? I've tried looking at [fseek](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php) but that uses the number of bytes, not the number of rows, and I don't know how many bytes 128,000 rows is.

How can I process the entire file without hitting the memory limit? I've been trying to get this working for the last 6 hours and I've not had any joy.

This is my code so far:

```
    // This script takes a long time to run
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);

// First we need to verify the files that have been uploaded.
$file = Validation::factory($_FILES);
$file->rule('import_update_file', 'Upload::not_empty');
$file->rule('import_update_file', 'Upload::valid');
$file->rule('import_update_file', 'Upload::size', array(':value', '8M'));
$file->rule('import_update_file', 'Upload::type', array(':value', array('zip')));
if (Request::current()->method() == Request::POST && $file->check())
{
    $file_name = date('Y-m-d-').'update.zip';
    $dir = Upload::save($file['import_update_file'], $file_name);
    if ($dir === false)
    {
        throw new Kohana_Exception('Unable to save uploaded file!', NULL, 1);
    }
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    if ($zip->open($dir) !== TRUE)
    {
        throw new Kohana_Exception('Unable to open uploaded zip file! Error: '.$res, NULL, 1);
    }
    $zip->extractTo(realpath(Upload::$default_directory), array('localauthority.csv', 'postcode.csv'));
    $zip->close();

    if( ! file_exists(realpath(Upload::$default_directory).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'localauthority.csv') OR 
        ! file_exists(realpath(Upload::$default_directory).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'postcode.csv'))
    {
        throw new Kohana_Exception('Missing file from uploaded zip archive! Expected localauthority.csv and postcode.csv', NULL, 1);
    }
    $local_authorities = Request::factory('local_authority/read')->execute();

    // We start by combining the files, sorting the postcodes and local authority names under the local authority codes.
    $update = array();
    if (($fp = fopen(realpath(Upload::$default_directory).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'localauthority.csv', 'r')) === FALSE)
    {
        throw new Kohana_Exception('Unable to open localauthority.csv file.', NULL, 1);
    }
    while (($line = fgetcsv($fp)) !== FALSE)
    {
        // Column 0 = Local Authority Code
        // Column 1 = Local Authority Name
        $update[$line[0]] = array(
            'name'      => $line[1],
            'postcodes' => array()
        );
    }
    fclose($fp);
    unlink(realpath(Upload::$default_directory).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'localauthority.csv');

    if (($fp = fopen(realpath(Upload::$default_directory).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'postcode.csv', 'r')) === FALSE)
    {
        throw new Kohana_Exception('Unable to open postcode.csv file.', NULL, 1);
    }
    $i = 1;
    while (($line = fgetcsv($fp)) !== FALSE && $i <= 128000)
    {
        $postcode = trim(substr($line[0], 0, 4));
        echo "Line ".sprintf("%03d", $i++) . ": Postcode: ".$line[0]."; Shortened Postcode: ".$postcode."; LAC: ".$line[1]."<br>";
        // Column 0 = Postcode
        // Column 1 = Local Authority Code
        if ( ! array_key_exists($line[1], $update))
        {
            echo $line[1]." not in array<br>";
            continue;
        }
        if ( ! in_array($postcode, $update[$line[1]]['postcodes']))
        {
            $update[$line[1]]['postcodes'][] = $postcode;
        }
    }
    fclose($fp);
    unlink(realpath(Upload::$default_directory).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'postcode.csv');

    echo '<pre>'; var_dump($update); echo '</pre>';
}
else
{
    throw new Kohana_Exception('Invalid file uploaded!', NULL, 1);
}
```

Comment: Use MySQL's [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html) in you're on MySQL.... or read row/insert/read next row in PHP, even if you use temporary tables to do any manipulation first.... but don't try to build an array of that data in memory before doing all the inserts

Comment: I'm using Kohana's ORM, not sure how to use temporary tables with that though.

Comment: periodically empty out $update. You just keep building and building and building it.

Comment: @MarcB, I need it all in `$update` though, so I can compare `$update` with `$local_authorities` to see what's changes, what is new etc.

Comment: That's where loading to a temporary database table is a benefit.... you can use SQL to check what's new between the existing data tables containing local authorities and the newly loaded postcode data in its temporary table, without blowing PHP's memory limits in the process

Comment: Ideally that would be great, but I need to manipulate the data. I only want the first part of the postcode and then take the second column, and match that with the second column in a different file and those two matched together are my final record in `local_authority`

Comment: That's the type of matching that you should be handling with SQL queries after loading the data into temporary tables on the database